# checking if a pixel is within a certain colour range

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an iPhone app where you can select a pixel from an image and it will return the RGBA colour details.

I need to be able to determine if the selected pixel is within a certain range of colour e.g. a light or dark variation of a specific colour.

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Have you considered using hue, saturation and brightness? `- (BOOL)getHue:(CGFloat *)hue saturation:(CGFloat *)saturation brightness:(CGFloat *)brightness alpha:(CGFloat *)alpha
`

Comment: It is something that I have considered, I'm just wondering how accurate it would be detecting if a colour is within a certain range.

Comment: I agree with @Zaph, once you know the hue, saturation and brightness, you could define a "3D sphere" around a specific point. Hue is what defines the color, saturation is how vivid your color is (or grayed), and brightness is the amount of luminosity. I would assume that you want a tight hue, and a loose  saturation and brightness values, no need to look at alpha if you do not have transparency.

Comment: @Resh32 Make your comment an answer.

Comment: @Resh32 Thanks, I have been playing around with this idea and it seems to be working well. I agree with Zaph, change the comment to an answer and I will happily accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will first have to convert your RGBA colorspace into HSBA (as suggested by @Zaph)

```
- (BOOL)getHue:(CGFloat *)hue saturation:(CGFloat *)saturation brightness:(CGFloat 
*)brightness alpha:(CGFloat *)alpha
```

Once you know the hue, saturation and brightness, you could define a "3D sphere" around a specific point. Hue is what defines the color, saturation is how vivid your color is (or grayed), and brightness is the amount of luminosity.

I would assume that you want a tight hue, and a loose saturation and brightness values, no need to look at alpha if you do not have transparency.